# Strange Java Timezone Date Conversion Problem

Tags: java, date, timezone

I want to convert `ms-since-1970-timestamp` to a date with timezone (Germany).

Here are two variants of code which worked - at least, I remember using it and it worked:

```
import java.text.SimpleDateFormat;
import java.util.Calendar;
import java.util.Date;
import java.util.GregorianCalendar;
import java.util.Locale;
import java.util.TimeZone;

public class TestDate {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Calendar cal = GregorianCalendar.getInstance(TimeZone.getTimeZone("Germany"), Locale.GERMANY);

        Date d = new Date();
        cal.setTime(d);

        System.out.println(String.format("%02d.%02d.%04d %02d:%02d:%02d", 
                cal.get(Calendar.DAY_OF_MONTH), cal.get(Calendar.MONTH)+1, cal.get(Calendar.YEAR),
                cal.get(Calendar.HOUR_OF_DAY),  cal.get(Calendar.MINUTE),  cal.get(Calendar.SECOND)));

        SimpleDateFormat df = new SimpleDateFormat( "dd.MM.yyyy HH:mm:ss.S" );
        df.setTimeZone(TimeZone.getTimeZone("Germany"));
        System.out.println(df.format(d));
    }

}
```

It's really strange, because I couldn't find the reason for a time-difference of 2hours.

It should be: `16:05:20`
The code prints: `14:05:20` in both variants.

Could someone please help me and tell me what went wrong here?

Answer (score 25):

This is the problem:

```
TimeZone.getTimeZone("Germany")
```

There's no such time zone ID, so Java in its infinite wisdom decides to just return you UTC without telling you that anything's wrong. Try this instead:

```
TimeZone.getTimeZone("Europe/Berlin")
```

Wikipedia has a [list of IANA time zone IDs](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_tz_database_time_zones), but it's somewhat out of date (at the time of writing); the [IANA data](http://www.iana.org/time-zones) is the most up-to-date, but it's not as easily browsable...

Comment: *in its infinite wisdom* Long live irony.

Answer (score 1):

I believe the problem is the default timezone on the platform you're running on.

`java.util.Date()` does have a time zone. It maintains "inherited" time zone information, which, it appears, is acquired from the system's default locale.

this code.

```
TimeZone tz = TimeZone.getTimeZone("GMT-03:00");
Calendar cal = Calendar.getInstance(tz);
cal.set(1953, 2, 22, 4, 20, 13);
Date dateTime = cal.getTime();
System.out.println(dateTime.toString());
```

yields this on my system, which is uses the PST locale: Sat Mar 21 23:20:13 PST 1953.

I don't believe that there is a way to use the `java.util.Date object`, or the DateFormat objects which use it, to accurately handle time information from a "foreign" time zone.

Comment: The mentions of locale are incorrect. Locale has nothing to do with time zone. Locale affects language such as names of days and months and default formats for generating textual representations of the date-time value. For example, you could have a time zone in India used with a locale of Québec ( `Locale.CANADA_FRENCH` ).

Answer (score 1):

The [Answer by Jon Skeet](https://stackoverflow.com/a/7041321/642706) is correct, you used an incorrect time zone name.

## java.time

Here is a solution using the modern [java.time](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/time/package-summary.html) classes that supplant the old legacy date-time classes that have proven to be so troublesome and confusing.

```
Instant instant = Instant.ofEpochMilli( milliseconds_since_1970 );  // Or Instant.now() for current moment.
ZoneId z = ZoneId.of( "Europe/Berlin" ); 
ZonedDateTime zdt = instant.atZone( z );
```

Generate a localized string to represent that date-time value.

```
Locale l = Locale.GERMANY; // Or Locale.CANADA_FRENCH, etc.
DateTimeFormatter f = DateTimeFormatter.ofLocalizedDateTime( FormatStyle.SHORT ).withLocale( l );
String output = zdt.format( f );
```

---

[image: Table of date-time types in Java, both modern and legacy]