# java Calendar, got wrong current date

Tags: java, calendar

Current time (Germany)

> 17.04.2015 at 09:35

Execute:

```
Date d = Calendar.getInstance().getTime()
```

Output:

> Thu Apr 16 16:30:11 GMT+00:00 2015

What's wrong ? Ok the timezone but the day is also worng.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/a/7613031/1793718

Comment: I would recommend using JodaTime to solve your problem, as the `java.util.Date` class and accompanying classes have problems.

Comment: @Tim Biegeleisen: the cause was something else but thanks for the Joda suggestion

Answer (score 3):

Ok, found the cause.

I should have specified that I'm executing java on an android emulator and the date was wrongly set to *16/04/2015* (time was wrong as well).

I post an answer just in case someone faces the same problem and doesn't think about the easiest and most probable reason :)

Comment: Yup, just happened to me. In my case, I guess Genymotion got confused when I put the laptop to sleep.